# How to audit file created under a specific path?

Tags: filesystem, security

I would like to know if there is an audit tool I can use to monitor the file created under a specified folder? I would like to know the user and program used (ftp, ssh , php)  to create the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options - there is a commercial product called [Tripwire](http://www.tripwire.com) which can watch folders or files for changes, or, as per [this post on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/141800/62544) you have [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/).

There are others that do the same sort of thing. Have a search for Tripwire alternatives.